# GetListItem Through Soap

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap, getlist

I tried to get list item through soapUI program.

**My request**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:GetListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:listName>Container Inspection Report</soap1:listName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:viewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            <FieldRef Name="Title" />
         </soap1:viewFields>
      </soap1:GetListItems>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**the response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
         <detail>
            <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">Element &lt;ViewFields> of parameter viewFields is missing or invalid.</errorstring>
            <errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000000</errorcode>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

second question how can I know my authentication NTLM?

My sharepoint version is office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

When using SharePoint Online, you should be using [REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints), not SOAP.  REST is more modern and supports authentication scenarios such as those required by SharePoint Online, that is: claims-based authentication.  Furthermore it’s responses are returned as JSON objects which do not carry the excessive overhead of XML, and therefore tend to return quicker responses.

Regarding your second question:

[There is absolutely no NTLM authentication in SharePoint online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/authentication).  [NTLM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) = NT ***LAN*** Manager

LAN as in Local Area Network.

SharePoint Online uses claims-based authentication. [See here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93018/difference-between-claim-based-authentication-and-classic-windows-authentication) for description of the difference

Comment: Do you clear explain to take a access token for list in share point, I tried to REST but I got access denied.

Comment: I recommend you read this post:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/sharepoint-online-rest-api-authentication-in-postman